# Detect empty columns to modify Bootstrap 3 grid

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

How can I detect if a **Bootstrap column** is empty or not in order to apply offset classes to center the rest of the non-empty columns on the same row?

I have a Bootstrap grid setup of **.col-md-4 .col-md-4 .col-md-4**. These columns cannot change, so I need a JQuery method for this approach.

My current code detects if a column is empty and depending on how many columns are empty and it adds an offset class to centre align the non-empty columns. This is what i'm looking for:

```
[...] [...]  [...]

   [...] [...]
```

Here is my code, although this is not accurate if 2 or more rows have an empty column, then the wrong offset applies and an effect like this one shows:

```
[...] [...]
   [...] [...]
```

**Current JQuery code**

```
var count = 0;

$('.section_2 .col-md-4').each(function()
{
    if( !$.trim( $(this).html() ).length )
    {
        count++;

        if (count == 1)
        {
            $(this).parent().find(".col-md-4:first-of-type")
                .addClass("col-md-offset-2");
        }
        else
        {
            $(this).parent().find(".col-md-4:first-of-type")
                .addClass("col-md-offset-4")
                .removeClass("col-md-offset-2");
        }
     }
});
```

**Example on jsfiddle**:

https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/95766/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First some notes about this problem:

**1)** An empty Bootstrap grid column still have a positive **non-zero** width, so we have to hide it when is empty.

**2)** You can check if an element is empty using this reduced condition: `!$(this).html().trim()`

Now, this is my approach to your problem:

```js
$('.row .col-md-4').each(function()
{
    if (!$(this).html().trim())
    {
       $(this).hide();
       var first = $(this).parent().find(".col-md-4:first-of-type");
       
       if (first.hasClass("col-md-offset-2"))
           first.removeClass("col-md-offset-2").addClass("col-md-offset-4");
       else
           first.addClass("col-md-offset-2");
    }
});
```

```css
.col-md-4
{
  /* Helps to visualize the layout */
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.box
{
  height: 75px;
  background: #ddd;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div class="section_2">
  <div class="container">

    <!-- ROW 1 -->
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="box">Box</div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="box">Box</div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="box">Box</div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- ROW 2 -->
    <div class="row">            
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="box">Box</div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>

<div class="section_2">
  <div class="container">

    <!-- ROW 3 -->
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="box">Box</div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="box">Box</div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- ROW 4 -->
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="box">Box</div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="box">Box</div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```